# Visual Studio different Text Editor autoformat

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete

In Visual Studio there are several ways of code auto-format.

1) It has hot-key combination to force code format: CTRL+K, CTRL+D

2) It has options "Automatically format on ';' or '}'

Assume we have code:

```
var B = option.Substring(
    option.IndexOf(
    "A",
    StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
    option.IndexOf(
    "C",
    StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

The Way 1 auto-format does not change the original code. Although, Way 2 does the trick.

Way 1)

```
var B = option.Substring(
    option.IndexOf(
    "A",
    StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
    option.IndexOf(
    "C",
    StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

Way 2)

```
var B = option.Substring(
    option.IndexOf(
        "A",
        StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
    option.IndexOf(
        "C",
        StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

**Problem:**  Original snippet and result 1 are the same.

**How to force CTRL+K, CTRL+D make code auto-format like Way 2?**

Comment: Actually Way 2 autocomplete is provided by Resharper 10. VS2013 does auto-complete as Way 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Way 1 works as well.

There maybe a problem with your Keyboard settings in VS. Follow these steps to reset your keyboard settings:

- Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Keyboard** > Click on **Reset**
  Button
- You will be prompted with a warning stating 'Keyboard mappings will reset to their default values. Continue?'
- Select 'Yes' and Press OK.

Your issues should be solved.

Comment: I have accepted this answer, because indeed Way2 auto-format is provided by Resharper. However, Aman gave correct solution to fix VS auto-format.